# socket.onopen() method won't be called in websocket or socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, socket.io

I've tried both socket.io-client for react native and websockets as described on react native official docs. The following code throws no error but also shows no change in backend logs.

```
const socket = new WebSocket('http://5aa3657a.ngrok.io/');
console.log(socket);
socket.onopen = () => {
  console.log('sending');
  socket.send('checkInDetected', 'hello');
}
```

and

```
import SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js';
this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://5aa3657a.ngrok.io/', { transports: ['websocket'] });
this.socket.emit('helloIeacon', 'yu');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am now working building a RN app, and is making use of Socket.io in it. Here is how how we have implemented it in our app.

Start socket inside the constructor of the component like this and manage the socket inside constructor.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.socket = SocketIOClient(<backend url>);

    this.socket.emit('senddata', { userid:1, userName: 'john'});

    this.socket.on('questions', (Questiondata) => {
      cw(Questiondata)
    });
}
```

Socket is now available wholly inside the component, and you can access it anywhere using `this.socket`

Comment: could you share the RN version and the library you are using exactly? On using socket.io-client I encountered the following error, "failed to set responseType property on XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: `"react-native": "^0.49.5",` and `"socket.io-client": "^2.0.4"`

Comment: Tried the following code but when I check the console log for this.socket it shows something like.                                                                           
    connected: false,
    disconnected: true. I am using "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
  "react-native": "0.49.5",
  "socket.io-client": "^2.0.4"

Comment: Did you get the connection to backend?

Comment: the backend console shows status code 400 or 200 but does not show response according to the event handler

Comment: Are you getting the socket connection event on backend?

Comment: Sorry guys it was a CORS issue. Solved it. Thanks